# Replace All using a list

Tags: functions, replacement

I have a more complicated case however a basic example is;

```
ci = {X1, X2, X3, X4};
g = ci[[1]] + ci[[2]] + ci[[3]] + ci[[4]];
f[t_] := g /. ci[[1]] -> ci[[1]][t] /. ci[[2]] -> ci[[2]][t] /. 
   ci[[3]] -> ci[[3]][t] /. ci[[4]] -> ci[[4]][t]
```

And I was wondering if there was a way to do this for the list without typing out each element. Everything that I have tried hasn't worked :(

Pls send help.

Comment: `f[t_] := Tr@Through[ci[t]]`?...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: ...or `f[t_] := Total@Through[ci[t]]`.

Answer (score 4):

Here are a number of one-liners that will define `f`

```
ci = {X1, X2, X3, X4};
```

This first one is perhaps the easiest for_Mathematica_ newcomers to understand.

```
Clear[f, t];
f[t_] := Evaluate[Sum[ci[[i]][t], {i, Length[ci]}]];
Definition[f]
```

This one is pretty easy to understand too.

```
Clear[f, t];
f[t_] := Evaluate[Plus @@ Through[ci[t]]];
Definition[f]
```

Currently the conciseness champion.

```
Clear[f, t];
f[t_] := Evaluate[Tr[Through[ci[t]]]];
Definition[f]
```

Using `Total` may be overkill, but it certainly does the job.

```
Clear[f, t];
f[t_] := Evaluate[Total[Through[ci[t]]]];
Definition[f]
```

Using functional iteration may seem opaque to newcomers, but it is concise.

```
Clear[f, t];
f[t_] := Evaluate[Fold[#1 + #2[t] &, 0, ci]];
Definition[f]
```

All the above, of course, produce

> ```
> f[t_] := X1[t] + X2[t] + X3[t] + X4[t]
> ```

Comment: What if the function isn't the summation? Like for example; (X1*X2+X3)^X4, like a more generic form?

Comment: "Using `Total` may be overkill" - tho `Tr[]` is certainly more compact, I still use `Total[]` for readability, reserving `Tr[]` for actually taking (generalized) matrix traces.

Comment: @TRL: define your `n`-argument function `f` and `Apply` it to your length-`n` vector `ci`: `f @@ ci`

Comment: @Guess `Tr` used to be an order of magnitude faster than `Total` on packed arrays; that was a better reason that brevity for its use in cases like this.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the comment about more general combining functions...

```
vars = {X1, X2, X3, X4};
g[x1_, x2_, x3_, x4_] := (x1*x2 + x3)^x4;
f[t] := Evaluate[g @@ (#[t] & /@ vars)];
```

Where g is specific form of the general 'combining function'.

This could all be done in place without defining vars and g...

```
f[t] := Evaluate[((#1*#2 + #3)^#4) & @@ (#[t] & /@ {X1, X2, X3, X4})];
```